# creating functionality for element to stop "setInterval" function (triggered by another element)

Tags: javascript

I have created an automatic slideshow - which starts after clicking "menu item". I'm looking for a way to "turn it off", when clicking different "menu item". The whole problem can be abstracted to a simple example:

Constructing functionality for "stop" `<li>` (that would probably utilize `stopInterval`). I can't come up with a solution, would anyone have an idea ?

```js
const li1 = document.getElementById("li1")

li1.addEventListener("click", slideShowAbstract)

function slideShowAbstract(e) {

    const y = setInterval(()=> console.log("playing"), 2000)

    }
```

```css
ul {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    list-style-type: none;
  }
  
li {
    margin: 1rem;
}

li:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
            <ul>
                <li id="li1">play</li>
                <li id="li2">stop</li>
            </ul>
```

Comment: Could you add a click event to the document body that stops the interval?
Edit:  Or you can add an event listener  on the ul t or anything outside of the menuitem that would cancel the interval.

Comment: I would need the stop to be triggered by another element

Comment: You can extract the `y` variable outside the "play" event handler function, then use it in the "stop" event handler function to clear the interval with `clearInterval(y);`

Comment: @GhassenLouhaichi `y` would had to start automatically then, and I want it to be triggered by element clicking

Comment: No it wouldn't, just define it as `null` outside, then assign the interval to it inside the "play" function, and clear the interval inside the "stop" function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a better  way ?

to avoid having global variables that can be jostled by side effects, use an object, to which you can add your useful methods.

```js
const 
  btPlay = document.querySelector('#bt-play')
, player = (()=> // IIFE  for object { play(), stop() } method
  {
  let // inside Object values ( closure )
    refIntv   = 0
  , counter   = 0
  , onProcess = false // security to avoid multiple setInterval processes
    ;
  function playerAction()  // inside private function
    {
    console.clear()
    console.log( 'playing', ++counter)
    }
  return {
    play()
      {
      if (onProcess) return  // security to avoid doing setInterval() twice
      
      onProcess = true
      counter   = 0
      console.clear()
      console.log('start playing')
      refIntv = setInterval( playerAction , 2000)
      }
  , stop()
      {
      if (!onProcess) return  // security to avoid doing clearInterval() twice
 
      clearInterval( refIntv )
      onProcess = false
      
      console.clear()
      console.log('stop playing')
      }
    }
  })();


btPlay.onclick =_=>
  {
  if (btPlay.classList.toggle('stopped'))  player.play()
  else                                     player.stop()
  }
```

```css
button { 
 margin : 1em 3em;
 width  : 5em; 
 }
#bt-play::after { 
 content : 'play';
 }
#bt-play.stopped::after { 
 content : 'stop';
 }
```

```html
<h5> case 1: same button for start and stop </h5>

<button id="bt-play"></button>
<!-- control by interface : same button for start and stop -->
<hr>

<h5> case 2: 2 buttons   </h5>

<button onclick="player.play()">play</button>
<button onclick="player.stop()">stop</button>
```

**interface control**:
if you have 2 buttons (start + stop), the user can click 2 times on the start button and you
you end up with 2 overlapping interval processes (or more) without the possibility of finding the reference of the previous setInterval since this variable has been replaced to reference the process of the following interval

if not you can also add a test verifying that there is no running interval process before.

Comment: @bartc I added `onProcess` varialbe to avoid issuing `setInterval()` or `clearInterval()` more than once in a row

Comment: your code is so well thought , an eye pleaser. it changes the way app works - for better, but I need that two button functionality overall.

Comment: @bartc  it doesn't change anything, this code also works if you use 2 different buttons -- I added this case

Comment: what does `=_=>` in `btPlay.onclick` stand for?

Comment: @bartc  basic ninja coding, character `_` is a conventional  for unused argument, you can also do `= () =>`

Comment: so its for clarity, like: there is a place for an argument here, but there isn't one currently

Comment: @bartc  not really, `_` is an accepted character like any other letters, in this case this is the event argument  `btPlay.onclick =e=>{ e.preventDefault() }` or  `btPlay.onclick =_=>{ _.preventDefault() }` will do the same things, the  character `_` is a purely conventional

Answer (score 1):

You can declare the `y` outside so that you can access it from multiple handlers.

```js
const li1 = document.getElementById("li1")
const stopElement = document.getElementById("stopButton")
let intervalTimer;

li1.addEventListener("click", slideShowAbstract);
stopElement.addEventListener('click', stopSlideShow);


function slideShowAbstract(e) {
  intervalTimer = setInterval(() => console.log("playing"), 2000);
}

function stopSlideShow(){
  clearInterval(intervalTimer);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Details commented in example**

```js
// Reference both items
const li1 = document.getElementById("li1");
const li2 = document.getElementById("li2");

// Bind both items to click event but call different handlers
li1.addEventListener("click", start);
li2.addEventListener("click", stop);

// Declare interval ID
let y;
// Define time interval
let t = 2000;
// Define counter
let tick = 0;
// Define the function to run on each interval
const log = () => console.log(t * tick++);

// Define the event handler called from li1
function start(e) {
  // If the tag clicked was #li1 and y isn't defined yet...
  if (e.target.matches('#li1') && !y) {
    // ...Initiate interval to call log()
    y = setInterval(log, t);
  }
}
// Define the event handler called from li2
function stop(e) {
  // If user clicked #li2...
  if (e.target.matches('#li2')) {
    // ...Stop interval...
    clearInterval(y);
    // ...reset interval ID
    y = null;
  }
}
```

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  list-style-type: none;
}

li {
  margin: 1rem;
}

li:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li id="li1">play</li>
  <li id="li2">stop</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: why is the interval ID reset, by `y = null` ?

Comment: So you can click `#li1` again. It's setup so you can only click `#li1` once, because if the user was allowed to click multiple times, there would be multiple intervals running. Note, `y` was declared not defined initially so it's value initially is `null`, it doesn't have a value until the user clicks `#li1`.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const startBtn = document.getElementById("start")
const stopBtn = document.getElementById("stop")

const timer = {
    timerId : undefined,
    idx : 0,
    start(){
        if(timer.timerId)
           timer.stop();
      
        timer.timerId = setInterval(()=> {
                        document.getElementById("status").textContent = timer.idx++;
                        console.log(timer.idx);
                    }, 1000);
    },
    stop(){
        if(timer.timerId){
            clearInterval(timer.timerId);
            timer.idx = 0;
            timer.timerId = undefined;
            document.getElementById("status").textContent = timer.idx;
        }
    }
}

startBtn.addEventListener("click", timer.start);
stopBtn.addEventListener("click", timer.stop);
```

```html
<button id="start">start</button>
<button id="stop">stop</button>
<br/>
<span id="status">

</span>
```

Comment: it works out the problem. but there is another catch that @mister JoJo and zer00ne pointed out: overlapping interval processes, when hitting play multiple times in a row

Comment: Please include an explanation of what the issue was and what you did to resolve it rather than just providing a long block of code. Posting code with no explanation doesn't teach the reader how or why the solution works. Spoon feeding code is beneficial to nobody.